# How to make a parallel arrow always go in an opposite direction?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \usetikzlibrary{snakes}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzstyle{rev} = [draw,decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,post length=1mm}]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',pics/parallel arrow/.style={code={\draw[-latex,snake] (#1) -- (-#1);}}]
\node (v) {v};
\node [below left=1cm of v] (a) {a};
\node [below right=1cm of v] (b) {b};
\draw[] (v) -- pic[sloped,rev]{parallel arrow={-0.3,-0.15}} (a);
\draw[] (v) -- pic[sloped,rev]{parallel arrow={-0.3,-0.15}} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It renders as such:

[image]

Here, I use the same arguments `{-0.3,-0.15}` for `parallel arrow`. However, one snake is coming in the opposite direction (this is how I want it), while another one goes into the wrong direction. Changing the arguments to `{+0.3,-0.15}` fixes the problem.

Is it possible to use one and *the same* `pic` command and always see the snake coming into the right direction (a reversed one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

There are three styles (`postaction` + `decoration`) that can be used as attributes for `TikZ` segments.  They produce a reverse snake arrow parallel to the segment.

- `rArrow` takes one argument (the side of the segment where the arrow will be placed); **it must be 1 or -1**.  It produces an arrow of fixed length placed at a fixed distance from the segment.  In the above figure, it corresponds to the black elements.
- `rArrowL` is the same as the previous one, but takes three arguments which are the side, a label, and the orientation of the label which **must be 1 or 0**.
  It corresponds to the red elements.
- `rSArrow` takes two arguments (the angle and the side).  It produces an arrow of variable length and variable distance from the segment (controlled by the angle argument).  In the above figure, it corresponds to the blue element.

**Remark.** `rArrow` contains a parameter `\d` in its definition which defines the length of the snake arrow.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} 
\begin{document}


\tikzset{%
  rArrow/.style={%  side = 1 or -1
    postaction={%
      decoration={
        show path construction,
        lineto code={
          \tikzmath{
            real \d, \a;
            \d = 1.4;  % length/2 of the snake arrow 
            \a = (-1)*(#1)*90;
            {
              \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (I);
              \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (F);
              \draw[arrows={Latex[width=2ex, length=1ex]-},
              decorate, decoration=snake]
              let
                \p1 = ($(F)-(I)$),
                \n1 = {atan2(\y1, \x1)},
                \p2 = ($(I)!.5!(F) -(\n1: \d em)$)
              in
              (\p2) ++(\n1+ \a: 2 ex) -- ++(\n1: 2*\d em);
            };
          }
        }
      },
      decorate
    }
  },
  rArrowL/.style n args={3}{%  side = 1 or -1, label, label orientation = 0 or 1
    postaction={%
      decoration={
        show path construction,
        lineto code={
          \tikzmath{
            real \d, \a;
            \d = 1.4;
            \a = (-1)*(#1)*90;
            {
              \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (I);
              \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (F);
              \draw[arrows={Latex[width=2ex, length=1ex]-},
              decorate, decoration=snake]
              let
                \p1 = ($(F)-(I)$),
                \n1 = {atan2(\y1, \x1)},
                \p2 = ($(I)!.5!(F) -(\n1: \d em)$)
              in
              (\p2) ++(\n1+ \a: 2ex) -- ++(\n1: 2*\d em)
              (\p2) ++(\n1+ \a: 4ex) ++(\n1: \d em)
              node[rotate={\n1 +#3*180}] {\small #2};
            };
          }
        }
      },
      decorate
    }
  },
  rSArrow/.style n args={2}{%  angle, side = 1 or -1
    postaction={%
      decoration={
        show path construction,
        lineto code={
          \tikzmath{
            real \c;
            \c = .15;
            {
              \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (I);
              \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (F);
              \draw[arrows={Latex[width=2ex]-},
              decorate, decoration=snake]
              ($(I)!\c!-{(#2)*#1}:(F)$) -- ($(F)!\c!{(#2)*#1}:(I)$);
            };
          }
        }
      },
      decorate
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (v) at (0, 0) {$v$};
  \node [below left=2cm of v] (a) {$a$};
  \node [below right=2cm of v] (b) {$b$};
  \draw[->, rArrow={1}] (v) -- (a);
  \draw[->, rArrow={-1}] (v) -- (b);

  \draw[red, ->, rArrowL={1}{fixed}{1}] (6, -1) -- ++(-3.6, -1.2);
  \draw[red, ->, rArrowL={1}{fixed}{0}] (3, -3) -- ++(3, 1);

  \draw[blue, ->, rSArrow={60}{-1}] (3, -.5) -- ++(3, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to make the length of this snake constant? I don't want it to change when the length of the main line changes.

Comment: Also, I need it to stay at the same distance form the main arrow, no matter how long is the arrow. Now, it seems, the distance depends on the length of the main arrow.

Comment: I propose some variants in the modified answer; the first one produces an arrow with fixed length and distance to the base segment. The idea is the same, only the way the necessary points are constructed changes.

Comment: Daniel, thanks a lot! Maybe you can also help me over there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664970/how-to-place-a-line-below-another-line