# How to place a line "below" another line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Thanks to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664824/1449), I managed to implement this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{math}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{%
  rev/.style={
    postaction={%
      decoration={
        show path construction,
        lineto code={
          \tikzmath{
            real \d, \a;
            \d = 0.7;
            \a = -90;
            {
              \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (I);
              \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (F);
              \draw[arrows={-latex},decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,post length=1mm}]
              let
                \p1 = ($(I)-(F)$),
                \n1 = {atan2(\y1, \x1)},
                \p2 = ($(F)!.5!(I) -(\n1: \d em)$)
              in
              (\p2) ++(\n1+ \a: 1ex) -- ++(\n1: 2*\d em);
            };
          }
        }
      },
      decorate
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{label}=[draw=none,above]
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,thick,every node/.style={draw,circle}]
\node (v) {v};
\node [below left=1cm of v] (a) {a};
\node [below right=2cm of v] (b) {b};
\draw[rev] (v) -- node[label] {$x$} (a);
\draw[rev] (v) -- node[label] {$y$} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It renders as such:

[image]

The backward going snake arrow is positioned wrongly at the second line. It must be somehow *automatically* placed `below` the line, similar to how `label` nodes are placed `above`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If the position of the decoration is always below the main segment, then it can be linked to the sign on the first coordinate of a vector.  Note that the function `sign` returns 0 for 0, so it's not so convenient here.

*Remark.* From an aesthetic point of view, it seems that you have a slight problem with the labels' position.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{%
  rev/.style={
    postaction={%
      decoration={
        show path construction,
        lineto code={
          \tikzmath{
            coordinate \I, \F, \v;
            \I = (\tikzinputsegmentfirst);
            \F = (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            \v = ($(\I) -(\F)$);
            real \d, \a, \r, \t;
            \d = 0.8;
            \t = atan2(\vy, \vx);
            if \vx<0 then { \a = 90; } else { \a = -90; };
            {
              \draw[arrows={-latex}, decorate,
              decoration={%
                snake, amplitude=.4mm,
                segment length=2mm,
                post length=1mm
              }]
              ($(\F)!.5!(\I) +(\t: -\d em) +(\t +\a: 1ex)$)
              -- ++(\t: 2*\d em);
            };
          }
        }
      },
      decorate
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->, thick,
  every node/.style={draw, circle},
  label/.style={draw=none, above}]
  \node (v) {v};
  \node [below left=2cm of v] (a) {a};
  \node [below right=3cm of v] (b) {b};
  \node [left=2cm of v] (c) {c};
  \draw[rev] (v) -- node[label] {$x$} (a);
  \draw[rev] (v) -- node[label] {$y$} (b);
  \draw[red, rev] (v) -- node[label] {$z$} (c); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! But fails if I use `\draw[rev] (v) edge (a);` Maybe you know what's wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Try `\draw (a) edge[rev] (b);` to see!  In fact the edge operation has similar effect as the node operation in that it adds something after
the main path has been drawn.  So you need to attach the attribute to `edge` which adds a `line-to`.

Comment: you are genius :) Maybe you can help me here too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664992/why-edge-bending-removes-decoration-on-the-path

Comment: I wouldn't start a new conversation on another page...  The problem comes from `linseto code` which is bounded to straight segments.  You need to use `curveto code` and it will work.  So, either you define another style, `crev` for example, or you add , in the same style `lineto code={...}, curveto code={...}` to cover both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    %\tikzstyle{label}=[draw=none,above]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,thick,every node/.style={draw,circle}]
        \node (v) {v};
        \node [below left=1cm of v] (a) {a};
        \node [below right=2cm of v] (b) {b};
        \draw[-latex] (v) -- node[draw=none,pos=.5,above] {$x$} (a)
            node[draw=none,pos=.5, below,sloped] () {$\rightsquigarrow$};
        \draw[-latex] (v) -- node[draw=none,above] {$y$} (b)
            node[draw=none,pos=.5, below,sloped] () {$\leftsquigarrow$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case I need to know the direction of the main arrow